# Проблема с массивами

Tags: массивы, php, проверка

Здравствуйте! Имеется задача: есть массив, который содержит в себе еще 5 массивов. 1, 4, 5 массивы содержат только цифры. Массивы 2 и 3 содержат строки, причем 2 массив может содержать до 2 элементов в себе (1 обязательный), а 3 только 1, который может быть пустым.

Нужно сделать проверку, которая будет по регулярке проверять массивы со строками и массивы с числами.

```
array (size=5)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => int 255
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => int 10
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'Главная новость' (length=7)
      1 => string 'Возможные варианты' (length=4)
  3 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '' (length=0)
  4 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => int 10
```

Как сделать компактную и быструю проверку? Я не могу понять, как правильно делать такую проверку. В итоге выходит костыль на костыле с созданием кучей левых массивов + очень много конструкций if else + циклов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$its_int = FALSE;
for ($i=0; $i <= count($mas)-1; $i++)
{
if (is_numeric($its_int[$i])) {$its_int = TRUE;}
}
```

и так каждый массив), по другому навряд ли получится.

Comment: for ($i=0; $i <= count($mas)-1; $i++)

меняете на 

for ($i=0, $count = count($mas); $i < $count; ++$i)

это намного ускорит обработку массива